# Linear approximation of $\cos(x) $ near $\pi/4$

Tags: calculus

> Find the linear approximation of $\cos(x) $ near $\pi/4$.

$$\cos(\frac \pi 4)+(-\sin(\frac \pi 4))(x-\frac \pi 4)$$

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}} + -\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}} (x-\frac \pi 4)$$

I'm not sure how to format some of this but am I on the right track here. Is there any more to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the first few terms of the Taylor series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cos^\left(k\right)\left(\pi/4\right)\left(x-\pi/4\right)^k/k!$$

where $\cos^\left(k\right)$ is the $k^\text{th}$ derivative of $\cos$. You can verify that your answer is indeed correct using a symbolic algebra package, such as [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Power%20series%20of%20Cos%5Bx%5D%20around%20Pi%2F4):

[image]

The dot-dashed line with negative slope is your approximation, and $cos\left(x\right)$ is in red.